# Getting the data from multiple lists within a file

Tags: python, selenium, bots, instagram

I am trying to create an *Instagram bot* using python. 
So my problem is that I have created a text file that will contain all the usernames of the people my bot follows and the text appears as follows.

These are the lines of code that I have used to append the file.

`followers_list` contains the list of all the users.

```py
with open("file.txt", 'a') as file:
    file.write(str(followers_list))
```

This is how the usernames are entered into the file.

```
["user1"]["user2"]["user3"]
```

Now I want to make a function that unfollows all the users present in the list. So I am going to need the username from these lists and I have been trying to find information on how to do that but I have not found anything useful. So I need suggestions on how to do that.

Comment: You should consider writing JSON to your file, then you can just load the list back in.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you don't have a completely valid data structure in python, so modules like `json` and `ast` are going to be tricky. If you are regex-inclined, you could try the following:

```py
import re
userstr = '["user1"]["user2"]["user3"]'

# capture everything except " in the group
re.findall('\[\"([^\"]+)\"\]', userstr)
['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
```

Where this will also work if there is a newline between user entries:

```py
userstr = '''["user1"]["user2"]
["user3"]
'''

re.findall('\[\"([^\"]+)\"\]', userstr)
['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
```

Otherwise, I'd agree with @MarkMeyer and try to get these users in some sort of json file format or something that is a bit more compatible with built-in python data structures. One suggestion to make life easy would be just to format users.txt like so:

```
user1
user2
user3
...
```

Then you can just do:

```py
with open('users.txt') as fh:
    # this will create a list of users, and strip()
    # removes leading/trailing whitespace 
    users = [user.strip() for user in fh]
```

And adding users is as simple as

```py
with open('users.txt', 'a') as fh:
    fh.write('userN')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have used another solution which I think is easier

Comment: No problem, just make sure to accept the approach you found works best for you

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest you to change: `file.write(str(followers_list))` to `file.write(",".join(str(followers_list)))`. Once that is done, you can simply read the file via `with open("file.txt", 'r') as f: lines=f.read()` And then make the for loop that you need: `for username in lines.split(",")`.

This is fast code, maybe needs some debug, if you can edit the question and add some examples we will be able to help you more. Only with an example of the variable `follower_list` should be enough, feel free to add fake data.

Note: Also instead of commas, using a json format would be nice too.

Comment: Instead of file.write(",".join(str(followers_list))) I wrote file.write(",".join((followers_list))) and it worked. Now the problem is that when I start the program again and the usernames get appended into the file, the first username doesn't get seperated by a comma from the last username of the previous session.

Comment: @Percy04 You can do: `file.write(",")` after the `file.write(",".join((followers_list)))`so there's a comma always for that next iteration! So, inside the `with` you will have two `writes`, one for the users separated with commas and an extra comma.

Comment: Thanks dude. the file.write(",") works perfectly in my program.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear what is the problem here. Whether is your write function or your read function you're trying to fix. Assuming the problem is the write function something like this should get the results that you want I guess.

```
 with open("file.txt", 'a') as file:
    for follower in followers_list:
       # assuming follower is a string therefore doesn't need to be converted
       file.write(follower)
```

Otherwise if you need to pick the username from each list just use indexing when you are reading your follower_lists

e.g.

```
for follower_list in follower_lists:
    follower = follower_list[0]
```